The classifications from the model do not align well with business expectations or the "X" metric
Could this discrepancy be caused by the threshold strategy? If so, how should I optimize or adjust these thresholds?
How can I better align the model outputs with the business context of "X"?( X is a ratio of call off contracts spend over total spend)
Are there any best practices to validate and refine the feature-target relationship in cases like this?
I have use logistic regression & decision tree for the case I had more than one million rows and select X as a target variable for classification algorithm. is there any suggestion how to improve to align with the expected values in X ???

Welcome fo DS.SE !!!
Aligning Model Classifications with Business Expectations
When classifications from a model fail to align with business expectations or the target metric (in this case "X", the ratio of call-off contracts spend over total spend), this discrepancy may stem from the threshold strategy, feature-target relationship, or model configuration. Below, I outline some steps for addressing these issues, with a focus on logistic regression and decision tree models.

1. The Threshold Strategy
Classification thresholds directly affect how well model outputs align with business priorities. The default threshold of 0.5 may not suit the specific context of "X".
Optimising the Threshold

Definition: For binary classification, the predicted probability $p$ determines the output class $y$:
$$
  y = 
  \begin{cases} 
      1, & \text{if } p \geq \text{threshold} \\
      0, & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
  $$

ROC Curve: Use the Receiver Operating Characteristic (ROC) curve to identify the threshold that maximises a business-relevant metric, such as True Positive Rate (TPR) or a custom metric derived from "X":
$$
  \text{TPR} = \frac{\text{True Positives}}{\text{True Positives} + \text{False Negatives}}
  $$

Cost-Sensitive Thresholding: Adjust thresholds based on a cost matrix to account for the business impact of misclassifications:
$$
  \text{Cost} = C_{\text{FP}} \cdot \text{FP} + C_{\text{FN}} \cdot \text{FN}
  $$



2. Feature-Target Alignment
Poor alignment between features and "X" can cause suboptimal predictions.
Feature Importance

Logistic Regression: The relationship between features ($X$) and the outcome ($Y$) is defined as:
$$
  \text{logit}(p) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_1 + \ldots + \beta_k X_k
  $$
Examine coefficients ($\beta_i$) to identify features that contribute most to "X".

Decision Trees: Decision trees split data to maximise information gain (eg., using Gini impurity):
$$
  G_{\text{split}} = \sum_{i} p_i(1 - p_i)
  $$
Alternatively, entropy can be used as a splitting criterion:
$$
  H_{\text{split}} = - \sum_{i} p_i \log_2(p_i)
  $$


Feature Engineering

Domain-Specific Features: Engineer features such as time-based spend trends or categorical groupings to improve alignment with "X".

Data Quality

Target Consistency: Verify that "X" is consistently defined and measured.

Handling Imbalances: Address target imbalance using techniques like oversampling (eg., SMOTE) or applying class weights. However please note that there is considerable disagreement about the exctent to which class imbalance is a problem in machine learning and statistics. See the following threads over at Cross Validated for details:
What is the root cause of the class imbalance problem?
When is unbalanced data really a problem in Machine Learning?



3. Model Refinement
The model’s structure and hyperparameter tuning significantly influence alignment with "X".
Logistic Regression

Regularisation: Apply L1 (Lasso) or L2 (Ridge) penalties to prevent overfitting:
$$
  L_{\text{ridge}} = \sum (\hat{y} - y)^2 + \lambda \sum \beta^2
  $$

Non-Linearity: Use polynomial terms or splines to capture complex relationships between features and "X".


Decision Trees

Pruning: Reduce tree complexity to prevent overfitting.
Ensembles: Employ methods like Random Forests or Gradient Boosting to improve accuracy.


4. Validation of Business Alignment
Validating alignment with "X" requires incorporating business metrics and stakeholder feedback.
Steps:

Custom Metrics: Define a metric directly reflecting "X" (eg., weighted cost of misclassification).
Stakeholder Engagement: Periodically review whether predictions align with business expectations.
Simulations: Test model predictions against historical data to evaluate alignment with "X".


Example: Optimising Thresholds in Python
The following Python code demonstrates how to optimise thresholds:
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve
import numpy as np

# Predicted probabilities
y_pred_prob = model.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1]

# Compute ROC curve
fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, y_pred_prob)

# Find optimal threshold
optimal_idx = np.argmax(tpr - fpr)
optimal_threshold = thresholds[optimal_idx]
print(f"Optimal Threshold: {optimal_threshold}")

Summary
To address discrepancies between model classifications and business expectations:

Optimise Thresholds: Adjust thresholds to align with business priorities.
Enhance Features: Engineer features that strongly correlate with "X".
Refine Models: Regularise and simplify models to improve predictions.
Validate with Business: Incorporate custom metrics and stakeholder feedback.


Is this LLM generated ?
